# Building a tree given 3 columns/nodes

Tags: javascript

First question, sorry if I'm missing some etiquette. I'm trying to build a tree that has 3 dependencies, I have successfully built "parent,child" trees before but adding the 3rd column is giving me headaches.

I have an array of objects that include 3 properties:

```
{Ref:1.1, Home: 1, City: City1}
{Ref:2.1, Home: 2, City: City2}
{Ref:1.2, Home: 1, City: City1}
{Ref:1.3, Home: 1, City: City1}
{Ref:2.2, Home: 2, City: City2}
{Ref:2.3, Home: 2, City: City2}
```

And need to build a tree with a structure similar to this one:

```
{City: City1, Nodes{Home: 1, Nodes{Ref: 1.1,1.2,1.3}}
{City: City2, Nodes{Home: 2, Nodes{Ref: 2.1,2.2,2.3}}
```

As I said, I am able to put the Homes inside the Cities by using a function similar to this one:

```
function getNestedChildren(arr, parent) 
        {
        var out = [];       
                for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {

                    if(arr[i].parent == parent) {
                         var children = getNestedChildren(arr, arr[i].name)


                            if(children.length) {
                            arr[i].children = children
                            }
                                  out.push(arr[i])
                        }         
                    }
                return out    
        }
```

but I'm not sure on how to take the third property into consideration for the tree. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array with the groups for nsting the object's data and look if a group exists and use it or creat a new group and push it to the level array.

This works for an arbitrary count of groups.

```js
var data = [{ Ref: '1.1', Home: '1', City: 'City1' }, { Ref: '2.1', Home: '2', City: 'City2' }, { Ref: '1.2', Home: '1', City: 'City1' }, { Ref: '1.3', Home: '1', City: 'City1' }, { Ref: '2.2', Home: '2', City: 'City2' }, { Ref: '2.3', Home: '2', City: 'City2' }];
    groups = ['City', 'Home', 'Ref'],
    result = [];

data.forEach(function (object) {
    groups.reduce(function (level, key) {
        var temp = level.find((l) => object[key] === l[key]);
        if (!temp) {
            temp = { [key]: object[key], nodes: [] };
            level.push(temp);
        }
        return temp.nodes;
    }, result);
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you do not like to have an nodes array in the deepest level, you could use `nodes` only in the level before the last level.

```js
var data = [{ Ref: '1.1', Home: '1', City: 'City1' }, { Ref: '2.1', Home: '2', City: 'City2' }, { Ref: '1.2', Home: '1', City: 'City1' }, { Ref: '1.3', Home: '1', City: 'City1' }, { Ref: '2.2', Home: '2', City: 'City2' }, { Ref: '2.3', Home: '2', City: 'City2' }];
    groups = ['City', 'Home', 'Ref'],
    result = [],
    nestedGroups = groups.slice(0, -1),
    last = groups.slice(-1);

data.forEach(function (object) {
    nestedGroups.reduce(function (level, key) {
        var temp = level.find((l) => object[key] === l[key]);
        if (!temp) {
            temp = { [key]: object[key], nodes: [] };
            level.push(temp);
        }
        return temp.nodes;
    }, result).push({ [last]: object[last] });
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This works wonderfully, thank you very much for this solution. I would've never came up with using this method, super useful and simple.

Comment: Sorry to bother again Nina, I have a quick question as to I'm not sure why IE is not liking the temp = { [key]: object[key], nodes: [] }; statement. It is saying that it expected an identifier, string, etc in the first [key] call. What could be a workaround for this part? The code works perfectly on Chrome for my purpose. Thanks!

Comment: IE does not know computed properties, you could take an empty object and asssign the property in bracket notation to the object.

Comment: Got it, added an empty object and seems like IE is liking it, thanks!